# Looking for Python/Django Framework to query GeoLocation Data in DB

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geocoding

I'm looking for a way to store a number of points, zipcode and their latitude and longitude in a database, and given a query point Q's lat and longitude, find the set of the points in the DB that are within x miles of the point Q.

I realize something like a kd-tree would do the trick. I was wondering if there is any built-in python library or django framework that could do this, probably more efficiently than I could.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.konekta.info: 
Konekta is an open development framework that makes community services accessible to mobile users. It includes bootstrap templates, an HTML5 mobile site, Geodjango and Django CMS. CC BY-SA 3.0
https://github.com/konekta/where-is-when-is